# Gapping in Lambda Expressions?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am having some trouble understanding how lambda-calculus works for gapping. How do you create a representation for "John bought and Bill cooked the turkey"?

EDIT-- I realize this was RNR. For a gapping expression such as "She ran a mile and he a marathon", what would the lambda expression look like? Thanks!

Comment: Your examples involves right node raising (RNR), not gapping. Gapping would be something like "John bought turkey, and Bill chicken". Check out the articles in Wikipedia on gapping and right node raising.

Comment: [(lambda x)(John bought x) & (lambda x)(Bill cooked x)](the turkey)

Comment: @TimOsborne- yup, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @GregLee- thank you! I know this was RNR, what about for an actual gapping for example "She ran a mile and he a marathon"?

Comment: I don't know about actual gapping.  Ross's formulation of gapping requires any number of like constituents to be gapped in the second clause when what remains will be one constituent inside the main verb phrase and one constituent outside that verb phrase.  (That's my recollection from McCawley's discussion, anyhow.)  I think finding a lambda formulation would be quite challenging.

Comment: I wonder whether there is any way to avoid predicate variables in the RNR of a verb phrase.  E.g., "I am now, and Bill will soon, be cooking a turkey."  I have a really nice syntactic theory that cannot describe such constructions, because my theory is first order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean something like (1b) and (2b), for (1a) and (2a),
respectively:

```
(1) a. John bought and Bill cooked the turkey.
    b. [λx . ⟦bought⟧(x)(⟦John⟧) ∧ ⟦cooked⟧(x)⟦Bill⟧](⟦the turkey⟧)
    c. ⟦bought⟧(⟦the turkey⟧)(⟦John⟧) ∧ ⟦cooked⟧(⟦the turkey⟧)(⟦Bill⟧)

(2) a. John bought the turkey and Bill the wine.
    b. [λP . P(⟦the turkey⟧)(⟦John⟧) ∧ P(⟦the wine⟧)(⟦Bill⟧)](⟦bought⟧)
    c. ⟦bought⟧(⟦the turkey⟧)(⟦John⟧) ∧ ⟦bought⟧(⟦the wine⟧)(⟦Bill⟧)
```

Importantly, (1b) and (2b) β-reduce to the usual (1c) and (2c), respectively.

In both cases, we essentially just abstract over the elided thing: "the turkey"
in (1), hence `λx` with `x` of type `e` (individual), and "bought" in (2),
hence `λP` with `P` of type `et` (predicate/set of individuals).

---

Remark: GregLee's answer requires some elaboration. He writes:

```
[(lambda x)(John bought x) & (lambda x)(Bill cooked x)](the turkey)
```

Notice that the two `x`'s are bound by two different λ-operators. Thus, this is
fact equivalent (switching now to my notation above) to:

```
[[λx . ⟦bought⟧(x)(⟦John⟧)] & [λy . ⟦cooked⟧(y)(⟦Bill⟧)]](⟦the turkey⟧)
```

So we have two different λ-terms being connected by `&`. Importantly, `&` here
cannot be a boolean connective (∧ above), because the two λ-terms are of type
`et`, not `t`. Thus, `&` is more like (a functional version of) set
intersection (∩):

```
[[λx . ⟦bought⟧(x)(⟦John⟧)] ∩ [λy . ⟦cooked⟧(y)(⟦Bill⟧)]](⟦the turkey⟧)
```

After β-conversion, this will of course be equivalent to my (1c) above, so in
that sense it's just as valid a meaning representation. However, the difference
is that in my version, we have just one instance of λ-abstraction; in this
version, there are two. Which one is more "correct" will depend on the
particular mapping from syntax to semantics, i.e. how abstraction arises
syntactically and whether we want one such instance or two.

Another consideration is that, for (2), the analog of GregLee's answer would
be:

```
[[λP . P(⟦the turkey⟧)(⟦John⟧)] & [λQ . Q(⟦the wine⟧)(⟦Bill⟧)]]([⟦bought⟧])
```

Once again, `&` must be the functional version of set intersection, but in the
λ-calculus, this `&` would actually have a different type than the previous
`&`. The first would be of type `(et)((et)et)` (intersection of two sets of
individuals), while the second would be of type `((et)t)(((et)t)(et)t)`
(intersection of two predicates/two sets of sets of individuals). Now, this
maybe isn't a very big deal, since you could maybe just define a suitable
polymorphic operator, or a family of such operators. But the nice thing about
my version is that both cases rely on just one abstraction followed by normal
boolean conjunction (∧).

Comment: Then how about "John bought, and Bill cooked, a turkey." ?  They could be different turkeys.

Comment: What type would "bought" be in sentence (2)?

Comment: @user11057, Butterball.

Comment: @GregLee: Good point, but that we can also formalize as:

      [λP . P(λx . ⟦bought⟧(x)(⟦John⟧)) ∧ P(λy . ⟦cooked⟧(y)(⟦Bill⟧))](⟦a turkey⟧)
    = ⟦a turkey⟧(λx . ⟦bought⟧(x)(⟦John⟧)) ∧ ⟦a turkey⟧(λy . ⟦cooked⟧(y)(⟦Bill⟧))
    = ∃x[⟦turkey⟧(x) ∧ ⟦bought⟧(x)(⟦John⟧)] ∧ ∃y[⟦turkey⟧(y) ∧ ⟦cooked⟧(y)(⟦Bill⟧)]

where

    ⟦a turkey⟧ = λS . ∃x[⟦turkey⟧(x) ∧ S(x)]

@user11057: "Bought" takes an individual (type `e`) and returns a truth value (type `t`). So what type is "bought"?